# Given dataset of state snapshots at time t how to transform it into dataset with each state's effective start and end times?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a dataset of S the goal is to produce a dataset of E where, S and E are defined below:

```
// event where start (s) is inclusive, end (e) is exclusive
case class E(id: Int, state: String, s: Int, e: Option[Int])

//snapshot with state at t for an id
case class S(id: Int, state: String, time: Int)

//Example test case
val ss: Dataset[S] = Seq(S(100, "a", 1), S(100, "b", 2), S(100, "b", 3), S(100, "a", 4), S(100, "a", 5), S(100, "a", 6), S(100, "c", 9))
      .toDS

val es: Dataset[E] = ss
      .toEs

es.collect() must contain theSameElementsAs
      Seq(E(100, "a", 1, Some(2)), E(100, "b", 2, Some(4)), E(100, "a", 4, Some(9)), E(100, "c", 9, None))
```

A state can have multiple snapshots (at different times) but the output should accumulate the effective start and end times. Also, the last active state is supposed to have no end date (option) in the output.

`toEs` above is defined as follows:

```
implicit class SOps(ss: Dataset[S]) {
    def toEs(implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataset[E] = ???
}
```

Following figure describes the
[desired transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTtl6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a solution using `flatMapGroups` which will spill to disk if a group is too large to fit in memory

```
def toEs(implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataset[E] = {
  import spark.implicits._

  ss
    .sort(ss("id"), ss("t"))
    .groupByKey(s => s.id)
    .flatMapGroups { (_, ss) =>
      new Iterator[E] {
        var nextStart: Option[S] = None

        override def hasNext: Boolean = ss.hasNext || nextStart.isDefined

        override def next(): E = {
          if (ss.hasNext) {

            val start = nextStart.getOrElse(ss.next())
            var last = ss.next()

            while (last.state == start.state)
              last = ss.next()

            nextStart = Some(last)
            E(start.id, start.state, start.t, Some(last.t))
          } else {
            val Some(start) = nextStart
            nextStart = None
            E(start.id, start.state, start.t, None)
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

It looks super imperative so not super happy :(